# How to take JSON from RappidJS KitchenSinkAngular6?

Tags: javascript, jointjs, rappid

I am using the RappidJs - KitchenSinkAngular6 apps module. I want to know where they are exporting the JSON object. I checked all the services and components I'm not finding any method to bind/export JSON. can you please help anyone.

Thanks in advance.